# error while reading fixed width file using spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Input: I have fixed width file as input 
 
Output: Need to create dataframe

```
val nullable = true
val schema = StructType(
  schemaString.split(",").map(fieldName => StructField(fieldName.trim, StringType, nullable)))


val rowRDD = sc.textFile(sourcePath).map(p =>
  Row(p.substring(0,11),p.substring(11,22),p.substring(22,33),p.substring(33,65),p.substring(65,73),p.substring(73,75),p.substring(75,95),
      p.substring(95,98),p.substring(98,101),p.substring(101,120),p.substring(120,139),p.substring(139,158),
      p.substring(158,177),p.substring(177,196),p.substring(196,215),p.substring(215,234),p.substring(234,253),
      p.substring(253,272),p.substring(272,291),p.substring(291,310),p.substring(310,329),p.substring(329,348),
      p.substring(348,356),p.substring(356,376),p.substring(376,395),p.substring(395,414),p.substring(414,434),
      p.substring(434,454),p.substring(454,473),p.substring(473,481),p.substring(481,501),p.substring(501,520),
      p.substring(520,539),p.substring(539,558),p.substring(558,577),p.substring(577,596),p.substring(596,615),
      p.substring(615,634),p.substring(634,653),p.substring(653,672),p.substring(672,673),p.substring(673,674),p.substring(674,675)
    )
  ) 
val inputDataWithSchema = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rowRDD, schema)
```

and schemaString also mentioned. 
I checked length of each line it's like 675, but when I collect the results I am getting an error:

`"java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 675"`

How can i fix this issue?

Comment: you can use try or Option

Comment: what do you mean by "it's like 675"? are they all exactly 675 or are they just approximately 675?

Comment: Exactly 675 characters

Comment: In my opinion you must check the length of string before Row creation.